# Prevent my android:theme from modifying dialogs?

Tags: android, android-fragments, styles, themes

My theme gives my app black text and yellow background, this works but I noticed it was also affecting AlertDialogs and making them look buggy.

I want to ensure my app theme only modifies Activities and Fragment's parent layout, but not dialogs or toasts. How can I restore them so they use the phone's default styling?

This is what I'm trying:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
    <!-- Colors -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:background">#fffdf12a</item>

    <!-- Restore Dialogs to default style -->
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle"></item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my knowledge you can't do that for Dialogs created by System, like the ones in the Preferences but you can change of Dialogs which **you create from sratch**

Here's what I found from another answer :

```
protected AlertDialog(Context context) {
   this(context, com.android.internal.R.style.Theme_Dialog_Alert);
}

public Builder(Context context) {
   this(context, com.android.internal.R.style.Theme_Dialog_Alert);
}
```

You can see the values are **Hardcoded** & hence can't be changed